# Getting the base url of my server with JAX-RS

Tags: url, jax-rs

How do I get the base url of my server with JAX-RS? Basically I want ""http://localhost:8080/.." when the program is on localhost and "http://www.theSite.com/..." when the program is on a live server. I am using Jersey Framework.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, you may use `myUri = uri.getBaseUri();`

Here how you get the Uri object :

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource{

  @Context
  UriInfo uri;

  @GET
  public String myresponse(){
    URI myUri = uri.getBaseUri();
    return ...
  }
}
```

You will have plenty of informations with UriInfo. [Check here the javadoc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)

Answer (score 7):

Use `getBaseUri()` of `@Context UriInfo`.