# In Java EE 6, how do I get the URL of a JAX-RS endpoint programmatically?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, apache-tomee

TomEE 1.7.2, Java EE 6, Java 8

I have this JAX-RS Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class CallStatsCatcherApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(RestEndpoint.class));
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/rest")
public class RestEndpoint {
    @GET
    public String echo(@QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

During startup, TomEE prints:

```
INFO:               GET http://localhost:8080/test-application/api/rest/      ->      String echo(String)
```

How can I get that URL programmatically **during startup**? I'd like to create a framework that advertises this URL locally on the network.

Answer (score 1):

To get server adress part you can try use something like that:
[Java EE: how to get the URL of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789359/java-ee-how-to-get-the-url-of-my-application)

But if you need IP address in startup bean, you can try use:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String ipAddress = ip.getHostAddress();`
```

Another option is to use:

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()`
```

But it may be associated with the server platform and you will need to search the property.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that _not_ in the request lifecycle though when there is no active HttpRequest?

Comment: Sweet... that's just a little bit farther... what about the port the server is listening on?

Comment: The port is not constant?

Comment: In production it will be, but for local testing it could definitely be different.

Comment: Ah crap... also need the context root. Sigh. This is difficult!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UriInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) class in conjunction with  [UriBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) class to mount or create URLs using the current path.

There is similar question in stackoverflow: [getting the base url...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652321/getting-the-base-url-of-my-server-with-jax-rs)

Comment: I saw that class too... the javadoc says it has to be called in the scope of a request, I was hoping to find something for boot time